# Batch File Move with Partial File Name to Partial Folder Name String

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory full of folders that are named in this manner:

ABC-L2-0001__**2ABC12345-0101**_xxxx

I need to move a lot of files that are named in this manner to the folder that matches the first 9 characters of the files:

**2ABC12345-0101**.xyxyxyx.yxyxyxyxy.model

Here's what I'm trying based on reading some older posts of similar requests and it isn't working for me.

```
:start
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir *.model /b') do (
  set filename=%%f
  set folder8=!filename:~13,9!
  set "targetfolder="
  for /f %%l in ('dir "!folder8!"*.* /a:d /b') do (
     set targetfolder=%%l
  )
if defined targetfolder move "!filename!" "!targetfolder!"   
)   
:end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not yet understand the mapping of the original filename ABC-L2-0001__2ABC12345-0101_xxxx to the target filename 2ABC12345-0101.xyxyxyx.yxyxyxyxy.model. Is the second name a directory name? From where did "xyxyxy..." come?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The directory name is the first string ABC-L2-0001__2ABC12345-0101_xxxx.  The second name is the file name.  The "xyxyxy" was just filler I placed in there for a bunch of other random numbers and characters that come after the first 14 characters that I am concerned with in the file name.

Answer (score 2):

You exchanged the positions of fileName and folderName. You don't take the first 8 characters from file name, *but characters 13,9*, and you don't look for these characters at middle of the folder name, *but at the beginning*. Check this fixed code:

```
:start
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir *.model /b') do (
  set filename=%%f
  set folder8=!filename:~0,9!
  set "targetfolder="
  for /f %%l in ('dir "?????????????!folder8!*" /a:d /b') do (
     set targetfolder=%%l
  )
if defined targetfolder move "!filename!" "!targetfolder!"   
)   
:end
```

You also should know that `for` and `for /D` plain commands are more efficient than `for /F` combined with `dir /B` command.

```
:start
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.model) do (
   set filename=%%f
   set folder9=!filename:~0,9!
   set "targetfolder="
   for /D %%l in ("?????????????!folder9!*") do (
      set targetfolder=%%l
   )
   if defined targetfolder move "!filename!" "!targetfolder!"   
)   
:end
```

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, you may check it; doing that will give rep points for both you and me. You may also upvote this answer when you have enough rep points to do so...